# cordova datepicker pluginsetting default value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, datepicker, phonegap-plugins

I am using Datepicker plugin

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.plugin.datepicker

in Cordova AngularJS Project

I am trying to set default value, for  userdatadob , which is coming from webservice ,which is not working. Although when I click on this field datepicker is appearing , and setting value.

I already have tested that the value is coming from Webservice , and it is showing in other input field

I tested plugin on normal Javascript it is working with value attribute

It is not working only on AngularJS , any help would be appreciated

Here is my code

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><input type="date"  placeholder="Date of Birth" ng-model="userdatadob" ng-click="userdobval()" />
```

Controller

```
$scope.userdatadob = '10/20/2015';
$scope.userdobval = function () {


    var options = {
        date: new Date(),
        mode: 'date',
    };
    datePicker.show(options, function(date){
      alert(" " + date);  
    });
}//userdobval
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put your default value into the `options` object like this:

```
var options = {
  date: new Date("10/20/2015"), // here you can put your date from your webservice
  mode: 'date',
};

$scope.userdobval = function () {
  datePicker.show(options, function(date){
    alert(" " + date);  
  });
}
```